# Кодировка для отображения текста JAVA

Tags: java, кодировка, файлы, utf-8

Добрый день. Возникла проблемма при загрузке текста из файла, не отображается кириллица. подскажите как испраивить.

```
public String read(File file) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File not found!");
    }

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")))) {
        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: ` BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))` 
не получается так?

Comment: нет. битые символы в тестовом поле после импорта, поэтому я и пытаюсь задать кодировку вручную

Comment: очень странно. можете приложить файл? 

попробуйте еще такой вариант:


` BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( fileName ) );
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
 if( reader.available() > 0 ) {
  stringBuilder.append( (char)reader.read() );
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
 running = false;
}

sout(stringBuilder.toString());

`

Comment: Кодировка в исходном тексте. Определите что за кодировка и декодируйте при чтении.

Comment: спасибо, как ни странно, но помогло..

Comment: Попробуйте битый текст пропустить через [Декодер](http://web.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/)

Comment: @studer а что именно помогло? опишите что вы делали

Comment: @ Senior Automator Изменил класс на основе вашего варианта и поставил в txt файлах юнфовскую кодировку. 
`class FileUtils {
     public String read(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
 
      BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( file ) ); 
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
      try { if( reader.available() > 0 ) { stringBuilder.append( (char)reader.read() );
      } } 
      
      catch (IOException ex)
    {
      System.err.println(ex.toString());
    } return(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответ взят из комментария

```
    BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( fileName ) );
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     try { 
        if( reader.available() > 0 ) {
        stringBuilder.append( (char)reader.read() );
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } 

     sout(stringBuilder.toString());
```